# SHOULD function return Null or Object of it?

Tags: c#

When we have a function, which returns a List of objects.
But if there is no objects, SHOULD function return List, which is NULL or Just return list as below ?

What is normal way of doing this?

If it should return NULL, how to fix it in my function below ?

```
Public class Student
{
    Public  String Name{set; get;}
    Public  int age{set; get;}
}


public List<student> Students(int age)
{
    List<student> studentList = new List<student>();

    /*Database not finds student */

    Return studentList;
}
```

Comment: Like `listBox.SelectedItems`, it return never NULL, but return an empty list "Count = 0"

Comment: This totally depends on the context and how this returned value is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to return an empty list. That way you don't need to check if it is null on the other side and you can directly iterate over it.

Also, that's how it works when you use Entity Framework. You run a query and if there are no results you get an empty collection. I'm pointing this out as an example and also for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

> DO NOT return null values from collection properties or from methods returning collections. Return an empty collection or an empty array instead.
>   The general rule is that null and empty (0 item) collections or arrays should be treated the same.

Using the [Framework design lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a big difference between *NULL* and an empty List.

It is all based on what you do when you call that function, if you're using a foreach loop, it makes more sense to return an empty list.

For most cases and if you don't have a special case : **Difference between No result found and some error happened**. Then go with the empty list approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in C#, but you touched, I think more abstract question "Do we need to use Null".

And there are a lot of holy wars about are Nulls are good or bad. From my opinion, it's bad and you should avoid them. In your function you don't need to return null list, because if you will think in commond life objects way...for example you came to School and asked to show you all Students with name "Sam". And you will recieve answer "Sorry, there are no students with this name", not "NULL".

So in your case you need to return or empty collection (no students), or throw exception NoStudentsException. And what you will prefer depends on your architecture.